# Application works in IE DEV Mode (F12) only + other Browsers but not in Regular IE

Tags: java, html, jsp, internet-explorer, browser

My application works in all of the browsers without any issue but in IE 11 it works only when I am in DEV mode by clicking F12. I've cleared the cache and cookies but still having the same issue. I had the same issue in Chrome but when I cleared the cookies it started working. Is there any work around for IE? I've unchecked the compatibility view setting as well.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like, there is no solution for this issue because of the fact that Microsoft has stopped supporting some old IE versions and in Normal view of IE we cannot change the Document mode. Document Mode can only be changes in Dev Mode.

Comment: Does your application rely on existence of console object? I'm not sure how IE11 handles this, but some versions of IE do not have console object until dev tools is open. If your application logs something to console, it might fail in IE without dev tools.

Comment: Or if your problem is really caused by wrong document type, have you tried setting doument type by x-ua-compatible? Try adding <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> with appropriate version to the beginning of <head> in your page.